# Shortcode displaying outside the div

Tags: functions, shortcode

I created a shortcode that is displaying the results as intended, but outside of the div or table cell where I placed the shortcode within my site. Is there a cleaner way to write this that will generate the code in the expected location?

```
<?php
function minisocialvar( $atts )
{
  $s = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
        'fb' => '',
        'tw' => '',
        'ig' => '',
        'yt' => '',
        'in' => '',
        'fk' => '',
        'align' => 'left',
        'size' => '',
    ), $atts ); ?>  

  <div id="<?php echo $s['id']; ?>" style="text-align: <?php echo $s['align']; ?>;">
    <?php if (!empty($s['fb'])) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $s['fb']; ?>" title="Follow Us On Facebook" target="_blank" class="fb-socialicon">
            <span class="fa-stack <?php echo $s['size']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if (!empty($s['tw'])) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $s['tw']; ?>" title="Follow Us On Twitter" target="_blank" class="tw-socialicon">
            <span class="fa-stack <?php echo $s['size']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if (!empty($s['ig'])) { ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $s['ig']; ?>" title="Follow Us On Instagram" target="_blank" class="ig-socialicon">
             <span class="fa-stack <?php echo $s['size']; ?>">
                 <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                 <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
             </span>
         </a>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if (!empty($s['yt'])) { ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $s['yt']; ?>" title="Watch Us On YouTube" target="_blank" class="yt-socialicon">
              <span class="fa-stack <?php echo $s['size']; ?>">
                 <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                 <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
              </span>
         </a>
     <?php } ?> 
     <?php if (!empty($s['in'])) { ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $s['in']; ?>" title="Join Us On LinkedIn" target="_blank" class="in-socialicon">
            <span class="fa-stack <?php echo $s['size']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
         </a>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php if (!empty($s['fk'])) { ?>
         <a href="<?php echo $s['fk']; ?>" title="View Us On Flickr" target="_blank" class="fk-socialicon">
            <span class="fa-stack <?php echo $s['size']; ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-flickr fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
         </a>
     <?php } ?>
 </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php add_shortcode( 'minisocial', 'minisocialvar' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the html in a variable and return it

```
$r = "<div id=\"" . $s['id'] . "\"..."; 
if (!empty($s['fb'])) {
$r .= "<a href=\" . $s['fb'] . "...";
}
$r .= "title=\"Follow Us On Facebook\" ";
$r .= "target=\"_blank\" ";  
return $r;
```

But every shortcode on your site should do this, for them to appear in the right order. As soon as one starts echoing things, it could mess up the order.

Comment: I've updated my shortcode to use return instead. But the IF statements don't appear to be working anymore. How should those be rewritten?

Comment: I edited the answer to include an if statement. Make sure you concatinate`(.=)` the rest of the string after it.